# Retrieve the next friday, unless if it's already friday

Tags: sql, oracle

The title problaby gives away what i'm trying to do, it's just curiosity, i'm trying to find the next friday from a set of dates, but if that date is friday i want to return that date and not the next.

Here's what i'm trying to do: (Using the employees table from Oracle)

```
SELECT first_name,
     CASE WHEN to_char(hire_date, 'DAY') = 'FRIDAY' THEN hire_date
          ELSE next_day(hire_date, 'FRIDAY')
     END as next_friday, hire_date, to_char(hire_date, 'DAY')
FROM hr.employees;
```

[image]

I don't see what's wrong with the query (those two marked records the date should be the same in the 2nd and 3rd column), it's logically correct in my point of view, i made a CASE statement and transformed the hire_date with to_char to see if it's friday and if it was return the hire_date, else return the next friday using the next_day function.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to just subtract one day:

```
next_day(hire_date - interval '1' day, 'FRIDAY')
```

If I had to guess, the problem with your code is with spaces at the end of the day name.

Comment: @MatheusFaria . . . I'm not sure I can explain.  It seems pretty obvious.  If today is Friday, then this gets the first Friday after yesterday, which is today.  Otherwise, "next Friday" is the same for today and yesterday.

Comment: It actually work, if i'm not asking much, could you explain me why subtracting 1 make it work?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be wrong?

Your query is almost correct; however, `to_char(hire_date, 'DAY')` returns a fixed-length string with 9 characters (since that is the length of the longest day name `WEDNESDAY`, when the language is English) and shorter days are right-padded with space characters.

Just right-pad the day so it has 9 characters:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
       CASE
       WHEN to_char(hire_date, 'DAY') = 'FRIDAY   '
       THEN hire_date
       ELSE next_day(hire_date, 'FRIDAY')
       END as next_friday,
       hire_date,
       '"'||to_char(hire_date, 'DAY')||'"' AS day
FROM   employees;
```

So, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees( first_name, hire_date ) AS
SELECT 'Alice', DATE '2020-03-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',   DATE '2020-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', DATE '2020-03-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'David', DATE '2020-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emma',  DATE '2020-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fred',  DATE '2020-03-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gemma', DATE '2020-03-15' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> FIRST_NAME | NEXT_FRIDAY | HIRE_DATE | DAY        
> :--------- | :---------- | :-------- | :----------
> Alice      | 13-MAR-20   | 09-MAR-20 | "MONDAY   "
> Bob        | 13-MAR-20   | 10-MAR-20 | "TUESDAY  "
> Carol      | 13-MAR-20   | 11-MAR-20 | "WEDNESDAY"
> David      | 13-MAR-20   | 12-MAR-20 | "THURSDAY "
> Emma       | 13-MAR-20   | 13-MAR-20 | "FRIDAY   "
> Fred       | 20-MAR-20   | 14-MAR-20 | "SATURDAY "
> Gemma      | 20-MAR-20   | 15-MAR-20 | "SUNDAY   "
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a7344a01cf46c152914880a41428cff)*